# multi idioma con Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Saludos a todos en la comunidad

Tengo un problema cuando quiero intentar colocar un sitio multi idioma, me he descargado los paquetes de idiomas y los he puesto en la carpeta resources/lang de Laravel 5.2

He configurado mi vista asi:

```
 <li><a href="{{url('lang',['es'])}}"><img src="digitales/RecursoSistema/imagenes/spain.png"> Español</a></li>
 <li class="divider"></li>
 <li><a href="{{url('lang',['en'])}}"><img src="digitales/RecursoSistema/imagenes/united-states.png"> English</a></li>
 <li class="divider"></li>
 <li><a href="{{url('lang',['zh'])}}"><img src="digitales/RecursoSistema/imagenes/china.png"> 中国</a></li>
```

He configurado mi ruta asi:

```
 Route::get('lang/{lang}',function ($lang){
    session(['lang' => $lang]);
    return \Redirect::back();
     })->where([
        'lang' => 'en|es|zh'
     ]);
```

He creado un Middleware al cual se llamo como LangMiddleware asi:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if(!empty(session('lang')))
    {
        \App::setLocale('lang');

    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Registre mi Middleware asi en el archivo Kernel.php:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \reconsafe\Http\Middleware\LangMiddleware::class,
        \reconsafe\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \reconsafe\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],
```

Y he colocado las rutas en un grupo principal del Middleware diciendole que apunte al grupo llamado 'web'asi:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
Route::get('lang/{lang}',function ($lang){
    session(['lang' => $lang]);
    return \Redirect::back();
})->where([
    'lang' => 'en|es|zh'
]);

 Route::group(['prefix'=>'principal','namespace'=>'\Principal'],function(){
    Route::resource('paises','PaisController');
    Route::resource('provincias','ProvinciaController');
    });
    });
```

El problema es que cuando hago clic en los enlaces de la vista, el idioma no cambia...sigue mostrando el que esta por defecto en el config/app.php lo curioso es que si hago clic en los enlaces se va por defecto en el fallback_locale...ya revise la variable de session y si guarda los valores que le envio.

Para asegurarme que Laravel si este tomando los valores del lenguaje, si pongo manualmente el valor en el config/app.php si funciona, el problema es si hago clic en los enlaces...

Honestamente no se que estoy haciendo mal...algo me dice que es el Middleware pero no estoy seguro, necesito de orientacion a ver que es lo que esta mal hecho.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciono de esta manera, usando Laravel 5.4. La carpeta resources / lang contiene archivos de localización. El nombre del archivo corresponde a la vista que se utilizará. Para obtener un valor de este archivo, simplemente puede usar el siguiente código:

```
Lang :: get ('localization_file_name.variable_name');
```

1- En `config/app.php` adiciona:

```
'locale' => 'ru',
'locales' => ['ru', 'en'],
```

2- Cree un middleware llamado `Locale.php` con este codigo:

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

```
use Closure;
use App;
use Config;
use Session;

class Locale
{
  /**
   * Handle an incoming request.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @param  \Closure  $next
   * @return mixed
   */
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
     $raw_locale = Session::get('locale');
     if (in_array($raw_locale, Config::get('app.locales'))) {
       $locale = $raw_locale;
     }
     else $locale = Config::get('app.locale');
       App::setLocale($locale);
       return $next($request);
   }
 }
```

3- Adiciono en `app/Http/Kernel.php` en `$middlewareGroups=[ ... ]` la siguiente linea:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class,
```

4- En `routes/web.php` adiciono:

```
Route::get('setlocale/{locale}', function ($locale) {
  if (in_array($locale, \Config::get('app.locales'))) {
    Session::put('locale', $locale);
  }
  return redirect()->back();
});
```

Espero te sirva de referencia.

Comment: Gracias...pero ya me di cuenta del tremendisimo error ....pffff increible que no me di cuenta de eso...hasta que depure el sistema...Gracias....

Comment: No hay problema, para eso estamos